# Delete the Rms file using j2me program

Tags: file, delete-file, j2mepolish, rms

I make a j2me application  work properly, but I want to delete the RMS file after same day like the file created in 3-3-2012 and delete  automatically the 10-3-2012 file.

Please help me with suggestions on how to delete the RMS file using j2me program. It is not required to delete the record; I want the delete the RMS file.

Answer (score 1):

use this method to delete an RMS file from device:

```
/**
 * A static method to delete a particular storage file
 * @param storageName Name of existing storage file
 * @return True if deleted, else False
 */
public static boolean DeleteStorage(String storageName){
    boolean isDeleted = false;

    try{
        RecordStore.deleteRecordStore(storageName);
        isDeleted = true;
    }
    catch(RecordStoreException ex){ isDeleted=false; }

    return isDeleted;
}
```